# Add to Kendo MultiSelect after MVVM binding

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui

I'm using the MVVM pattern with a Kendo MultiSelect on one of my pages. The issue I'm having is adding an item to the MultiSelect DataSource.

The JavaScript I have:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    productHandlingDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Helper/GetProductHandlingTypes",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET"
            }
        }
    })
});

kendo.bind($("#buyer-profile-register"), viewModel);
```

Select tag on my view:

```
<select data-role="multiselect"
    data-placeholder="Select Type(s):"
    data-text-field="Name"
    data-value-field="Id"
    data-bind="source: productHandlingDataSource"
    style="width: 100%;">
</select>
```

I've tried just doing the standard `viewModel.productHandlingDataSource.add({ Name: "Other" })` but when I load the page it hasn't been added to the MultiSelect.

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you provide the `select` tag?

Comment: @Win Just added it to the post

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything wrong in the above code. Could you ensure that API return the valid data?

https://plnkr.co/edit/zgu5ADxhlk5Tbq6B8XXM

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="buyer-profile-register">
  <h4>MultiSelect</h4>
  <select data-role="multiselect"
          data-placeholder="Select Type(s):"
          data-text-field="ProductName"
          data-value-field="ProductID"
          data-bind="source: productHandlingDataSource"
          ></select>
           
<script>
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        productHandlingDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                }
            }
        })
    });
    kendo.bind($("#buyer-profile-register"), viewModel);
</script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah all of the data is being returned correctly. The Multiselect is populated with all of the items that are returned. My issue though is adding another item to the datasource that doesn't come in with all of the other data normally. So the multiselect may have three items with the names: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3. And I want to add another item into it with the name of "Other". Sorry if I'm not explaining myself clearly.